# How to use HTML button to call my JavaScript function then display result of JavaScript code which generates random token

Tags: javascript, html, forms

So I'm working on an HTML page that contains a form where a user can send out an email invitation to join a website. I want a random token to be generated and sent along with the invitation, however first I want the user sending the invitation to be able to generate and see the token. Thus I've created a button in the HTML form to generate the token and I'm trying to get the button to call upon my token generator code I have written in JavaScript and then display the generated token within the HTML form before the user submits the invitation email. Here is my HTML for the form and the token generator button is highlighted in bold.

```html
<div class="form-group">
<form id="invitationForm" form action="https://getform.io/f/d59e4f74-57a0-412a-a77f-c100c59142d3" method="POST">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Name</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="Full Name" class="form-control input-md" required="">
    
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="email">Email</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" required>  
  </div>
    ** <button onclick="token()">Generate Token</button>
     <div id="result"></div>**
     <p></p>   
        <input type="submit" value="Send Invitation">
</div>
```

And here is my Javascript code to generate token

```
function token() {
const random = size => btoa(
  String.fromCharCode(
    ...crypto.getRandomValues(
      new Uint8Array(size)
    )
  )
).replaceAll('+', 'x').replaceAll('/', 'I').slice(0, size)

for (let i = 5; i--;) console.log(random(16))}
```

How do I get the token generator, upon clicking the button, to output the token to the HTML form (ideally in a text box above the "Send Invitation" button)?

I tried adding

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "String.fromCharCode"
```

to the JavaScript code to get it to output to the HTML however that did not work.

Comment: The button is going to submit the form unless you change it to `type="button"`.

Comment: If you fix that, assigning the token to `innerHTML` of the div will do what you want.

Comment: But if you want the token to be included in the form submission, you should put it in the value of an input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing first, you don't have a text box above the `Send Invitation` button. You have `div` with the `id="result"`. You are already getting the desired result in the logs. You just need to use the returned value of a function to show it in a `result` div. Also, one of the mentions is about specifying the type of a button. The default `type` is `submit`. So, you can change that to `button` so that your form is not sent every time you generate a new token.

**Solution:**

```html
<div class="form-group">
<form id="invitationForm" form action="https://getform.io/f/d59e4f74-57a0-412a-a77f-c100c59142d3" method="POST">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Name</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="Full Name" class="form-control input-md" required="">
    
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="email">Email</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" required>  
  </div>
    <button onclick="token()" type="button">Generate Token</button>
     <div id="result"></div>
     <p></p>   
        <input type="submit" value="Send Invitation" click="token()">
</div>

<script>
function token() {
const random = size => btoa(
  String.fromCharCode(
    ...crypto.getRandomValues(
      new Uint8Array(size)
    )
  )
).replaceAll('+', 'x').replaceAll('/', 'I').slice(0, size)

for (let i = 5; i--;) {
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = random(16)
 }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the output element to display the token to the user and a hidden input element to send the same token in the POST request.

```js
document.forms.invitationForm.generatetoken.addEventListener('click', e => {
  let form = e.target.form;
  let tokenstr = token();
  form.token.value = form.tokenout.value = tokenstr;
});


function token() {
  const random = size => btoa(String.fromCharCode(...crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(size)))).replaceAll('+', 'x').replaceAll('/', 'I').slice(0, size);
  return random(16);
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <form name="invitationForm" id="invitationForm" action="/test" method="POST">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Name</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <input id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="Full Name" class="form-control input-md" required="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="email">Email</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" required>
      </div>
      ** <button type="button" name="generatetoken">Generate Token</button>
      <output name="tokenout"></output><input type="hidden" name="token">**
      <p></p>
      <input type="submit" value="Send Invitation">
    </div>
  </form>
```